# Update @Id (using identity strategy) in H2 JPA test

Tags: java, h2, jpa-2.0

I've a test that checks the id of the last insertion I'm using H2 for test

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Guy implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(nullable = false)
  protected Long id;
  @Column(nullable = false)
  protected String name;
}
```

Here is the Test

```
@Test
public void getTest() {
  String jsonResponse = "{\"name\":\"andrew\"}";
  Response response = given().body(jsonResponse).header("Content-Type", 
 "application/json").header("Client", 123).post("/thin/guy");

  assertEquals(HttpServletResponse.SC_CREATED,response.getStatusCode());
  //here the record was created

  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.getBody().print());
  Response resGet = given().header("Client",123).get("/thin/guy/"+String.valueOf(jsonObject.get("id")));
  assertEquals(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK, resGet.getStatusCode());

  //this is the response "{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"andrew\"}"
  JSONObject getGuy = new JSONObject(resGet.getBody().print());

  assertEquals(5000L,Long.valueOf(getGuy.get("id").toString()));
}
```

How can i do to make H2database, that runs only in test scope, returns the id of the insertion with de value for example 5000.
It's possible the set up the star value for the entity Guy in the test scope? Thanks!

Comment: You can set the `identity` seed to a specific value. Yet I would advise against checking the ID. You should check every other value but the ID

Comment: Where can i set de _identity_? in pom file? i know.. the ID..its a very rare situation but has too be like that

Comment: its a database operation. for MSSQL its `DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[TestTable]', RESEED, 0);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do NOT check for actual value of an ID of a newly created object.

- There is no reason for checking the id. The id is generated by the DB engine, but you use a different engine during tests, so your test-case will test the behaviour of your test environment...
- Tests can run in random order, so at the moment you add more tests or change test data your old tests will start failing.

If you really want to test something then test the properties of the newly created object (as [XtremeBaumer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7109162/xtremebaumer) suggested).
Or you can test if the object returned during creation is exactly the same as the object returned during the GET request.

```
assertEquals(jsonObject, testGuy);
```